# How to load a video in opencv(python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am a begginer in OpenCV and Python.
I tried to load a video and displaying it using code given below:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('G:\3d scanner\2.mmv')
while(1):
    _ , img2=cap.read()
    cv2.namedWindow('video',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('video',img2)            
    k=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k==27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But it showing the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
File "test3.py", line 8, in <module>
cv2.imshow('video',img2)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

There are previous questions on this site regarding this issue but the answers 
given were using cv library but not cv2.

Any idea of what is wrong in this?

Comment: Which version of OpenCV and Python are you using?

Answer (score 8):

This might help you:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('linusi.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If it doesn't work, there are a lot of useful explanations in their documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: great little example, worked like a dream on raspberry pi 3b

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple important differences when using VideoCapture on a video file.  First off, there's no built in frame delays like when you're capturing from a webcam.  Since most computers are very powerful these days, unless you deliberately introduce a delay between frames, the video will be displayed in a blink of an eye.

Secondly, the video has an end unlike input from your webcam, so you need to explicitly handle that case.  I suspect what's happening in your case is that the video is completing in a matter of milliseconds, and then the final `cap.read()` is returning an empty matrix which `imshow()` subsequently complains about.

See [Opening video with openCV +python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354000/opening-video-with-opencv-python).  One of the answers in there is directly applicable to your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have both webcam and video file inputs, in different threads, and because the absence of `imshow`, `waitKey` doesn't work. I didn't understand why my code broke until read your answer: video run so fast, that it ended before the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I  think you have no cascade file that helps it determine what to compare with and when to exit. Try the following code and see.

```
import cv2 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
    Cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarCasade.xml")
    while(True):
         ret, frame = cap.read()
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
         if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the cv::Mat that you tried to access was not created. In this case, since you are trying to grab frames from a video, the reason could be one of the following:

1. The path to the video is not correct (on some platforms you might want to try `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('G:/3d scanner/2.mmv')`)
2. OpenCV could not retrieve frames from the video due to the lack of support for this format.

Answer (score 0):

use ("%s" %parameter)
and do not use ("%s",parameter)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
outputFolder = "picture_output"
videoList = glob.glob("video/*.mp4")
video=videoList[0].split('\\')[1]
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("video/%s" %video)
```